# Удаление элементов стоящих на нечетных позициях в двусвязном списке - C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

Здравствуйте! Как можно написать метод, который бы удалял элементы двусвязного списка, стоящие на нечетных позициях. Интересует именно метод класса.

Я написал некое решение: создал новый список, добавил туда элементы, стоящие на четных позициях; очистил список, для которого вызывался метод; в этот же список занёс элементы из нового списка.

```
public void RemoveAtOddPosition()
    {
        LinkedList<T> newList = new LinkedList<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                newList.Add(this[i]);
            }
        }

        Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < newList.Count(); i++)
        {
            Add(newList[i]);
        }
    }
```

Но может есть какое-либо правильное решение с использованием ссылок на предыдущий и следующий элементы?

Класс Node

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Previous { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

    public Node(T data)
    {
        Data = data;                        
    }
}
```

Класс LinkedList

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    Node<T> head;
    Node<T> tail;
    int count;

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return count == 0;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            Node<T> current = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                if (current.Next == null)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                current = current.Next;
            }
            return current.Data;
        }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Двунаправленный список");
        Node<T> tmp = head;
        while (tmp != null)
        {
            Console.Write(tmp.Data + " ");
            tmp = tmp.Next;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        head = tail = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(data);

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.Next = node;
            node.Previous = tail;
        }
        tail = node;
        count++;
    }

    public void RemoveAtOddPosition()
    {
        LinkedList<T> newList = new LinkedList<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                newList.Add(this[i]);
            }
        }

        Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < newList.Count(); i++)
        {
            Add(newList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "может есть какое-либо правильное решение" - конечно есть. Это делается за один проход, связыванием `Previous/Next` элементов на четных позициях, без постоянного получения элементов по индексу, что в данном случае является дорогой операцией.

Comment: тогда как мне получить доступ к элементам? оставить цикл, оставить условие, а дальше? через итератор не получается достать Previous/Next элементы.

Comment: А класс `LinkedList<T>` Ваш?

Comment: если с точки зрения написания - мой. а так реализация подсмотрена на некоторых источниках

Comment: То есть Вы можете вывести свойства `Head` и `Tail` наружу из `LinkedList<T>`?

Comment: Пардон, погодите, так метод `RemoveAtOddPosition` - это метод `LinkedList<T>`. Занчит у Вас уже есть доступ к `head` и `tail`.

Comment: верно. `head` и `tail` прописаны в классе

Answer (score 1):

Это делается за один проход, связыванием Previous/Next элементов на четных позициях, без постоянного получения элементов по индексу, что в данном случае является дорогой операцией.

```
public void RemoveAtOddPosition()
{
  int index = 0;
  Node<T> current = head; // at position 0, leave it in list
  while (current != null && current.Next != null)
  {
    // we come here knowing, that current was at even position:
    // need to remove current.Next
    current = current.Next; // now current is at odd index, take it out:

    current.Previous.Next = current.Next;
    if (current.Next != null)
      current.Next.Previous = current.Previous;

    // put current to next even index:
    current = current.Next;
  }

  // TODO: recalculate count and tail - left as an exercise for the reader 

  // this can also be done inside while loop above
  tail = null;
  count = 0;
  current = head;
  while (current != null)
  {
    count++;
    if (current.Next == null)
      tail = current;
    current = current.Next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Я разобрался с пересчетом элементов в списке: добавил `count--` в тело цикла последней строкой. А вот с хвостовым элементом немного неясно. Допустим, есть последовательность `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, в которой `tail` это `10` При удалении элементов на нечетных местах остаются элементы `1,3,5,7,9`. Получается, что хвостовой элемент тоже был удален. Вероятно, нужно каждый раз делать `tail = current.Next` внутри цикла?

Comment: @БыстровДмитрий добавил в коде ответа