# Удаление максимального элемента из двунаправленной очереди (дек)

Tags: c#, data-structures

Здравствуйте! Необходимо реализовать метод, который удаляет максимальный элемент в двунаправленной очереди.

Класс Node

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Previous { get; set; }

    public Node(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Класс Dequeue

```
public class Dequeue<T>
{
    Node<T> head;
    Node<T> tail;
    int count;

    public void Clear()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Дек");
        Node<T> node = head;

        while (node != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Data + " ");
            node = node.Next;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void AddLast(T data)
    {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(data);

        if (head == null)
            head = node;
        else
        {
            tail.Next = node;
            node.Previous = tail;
        }
        tail = node;
        count++;
    }

    public void AddFirst(T data)
    {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(data);
        Node<T> temp = head;
        node.Next = temp;
        head = node;
        if (count == 0)
            tail = head;
        else
            temp.Previous = node;
        count++;
    }

    public T RemoveLast()
    {
        if (count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        T output = tail.Data;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            head = tail = null;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = tail.Previous;
            tail.Next = null;
        }
        count--;
        return output;
    }

    public T RemoveFirst()
    {
        if (count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        T output = head.Data;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            head = tail = null;
        }
        else
        {
            head = head.Next;
            head.Previous = null;
        }
        count--;
        return output;
    }
```

Есть один вариант. Можно каждый раз удалять первый элемент, перемещая его в конец очереди. Так выполнять до тех пор, пока максимальный элемент не окажется в начале очереди, откуда его просто можно будет удалить. Внести такие проверки, при которых максимальный элемент может находится как в начале очереди, так и в конце, тогда удаление будет осуществляться просто методами `RemoveFirst/RemoveLast`. Но такие действия приведут к тому, что порядок элементов измениться. Возможно, это можно сделать как-то с помощью `next/previous` ссылок?

Comment: то есть Вы не уловили идею отсюда 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755299 ? И мои усилия пропали втуне?

Comment: А как для произвольного типа `T` определяется максимальность элемента?

Comment: @Igor Я думал, что здесь другая логика нежели в той задаче

Comment: @БыстровДмитрий Логика может и другая, но принцип тот же. Вам же, я надеюсь, важен принцип, а не чтоб Вам кто-нибудь код написал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, но нужен будет метод для сравнения элементов типа `T`, для этого я воспользовался стандартным классом `Comparer<T>`:

```
public T RemoveMax(Comparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (count == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    // Если ничего не передали - используем Comparer по-умолчанию
    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    // Начальные значения - голова очереди
    var maxNode = head;
    var current = head;
    // Пока есть элементы
    while (current.Next != null)
    {
        // перебираем их по очереди
        current = current.Next;
        // если текущий элемент больше текущего максимального
        if (comparer.Compare(maxNode.Data, current.Data) < 0)
            // берем в качестве максимального текущий
            maxNode = current;
    }
    // Вынимаем максимальный из очереди, подменяя ссылки в предыдущем
    if (maxNode.Previous != null)
        maxNode.Previous.Next = maxNode.Next;
    // и следующем элементах
    if (maxNode.Next != null)
        maxNode.Next.Previous = maxNode.Previous;
    // Возвращаем максимальный (если надо)
    return maxNode.Data;
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
var dequeue = new Dequeue<int>();
...
dequeue.RemoveMax();
```

или так:

```
class People
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    ...
}

class PeopleComparer : Comparer<People>
{
    public override int Compare(People x, People y)
    {
        return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x.Age, y.Age);
    }
}
```

И:

```
var dequeue = new Dequeue<People>();
...
dequeue.RemoveMax(new PeopleComparer());
```